# Are business objects meant to have behaviour?

Tags: c#, wcf, enterprise

I'm just looking for clarification here as I feel like I'm basically duplicating code and potentially over-engineering my project.

I've got a project split into a 5 separate parts; the front end client (WPF), a WCF service , a business logic DLL, a data access DLL (using EF6) and the database itself.

I found that my Data Transfer Objects (DTO's) (in the service project) are almost identical to my business objects (BO's) with the exception that my DTOs have DataMember/Contact attributes.

So for example, I have a DTO and BO for contact information that look like this:

```
// ContactInformationDto.cs
[DataContract]
public class ContactInformationDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

// ContactInformationBo.cs
public class ContactInformationBo
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm thinking that the business objects should contain methods to validate its state, for instance:

```
internal bool ValidateEmailAddress(ref string message)
{
    // Validation logic here.
}
```

However a lot of the texts I've read so far seem to advocate having a business object that just consists of properties (basically a POCO) and then using a 'business logic layer' to do all the validation/access. e.g. Translating my EF object to a BO, mapping the properties and returning it.

How should I proceed with this? All I want to know is should I putting my business logic inside the business objects or should they be separated into one class which is essentially a POCO and another class which does all the access/validation routines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is subjective and would vary on your requirements. Having the domain objects with only POCO classes is what Martin fowler calls Anemic Domain. A DDD approach would be to have your business logic in the domain objects but for an app with simple business logic it perhaps doesn't pay off the added complexity you'll need for the mappings between layers. On the other hand some would argue splitting domain objects and logic follows the single responsibility principle.